# Use Amazon SSE (Server-Side Encryption) in s3-put command

Tags: amazon-s3

I've read a [document about using SSE](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?UsingEncryption.html), but I cannot find how do I use SSE when storing files on S3 using `s3-put` command from [s3-bash](http://code.google.com/p/s3-bash/).

I run the backup storage procedure like this:

```
./s3-put -k ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS -s aws-key -T dbbackup/2011-10-10.sql /dbbackup/2011-10-10.sql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found the answer.

You change the line to look like:

```
./s3-put -k ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS -s aws-key -a aws-headers -T dbbackup/2011-10-10.sql /dbbackup/2011-10-10.sql
```

And create an `aws-headers` file that contains the line:

```
x-amz-server-side-encryption: AES256
```

Then it will send required request header that tells S3 to encrypt the content.